# How to list all files uploaded to storage bucket in Google Storage Bucket?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have numerous files uploaded in google cloud storage bucket. I want to perform operations on the names of all files for that particular bucket. 
how can I achieve it?

Comment: I suggest reading about the Cloud Storage list API. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-nodejs) shows an example of listing all files in a bucket using the provided node SDK.  You will want to use the [getFiles()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) method of a Bucket object.

> ```
> // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
>
> // Imports the Google Cloud client library
> const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
>
> // Creates a client
> const storage = new Storage();
>
> async function listFiles() {
>   // Lists files in the bucket
>   const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
>
>   console.log('Files:');
>   files.forEach(file => {
>     console.log(file.name);
>   });
> }
>
> listFiles().catch(console.error);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is suitable for client side.
For Node environment as per question, Refer Doug Stevenson's answer

You need to use `listAll()` method to get all file Names.

Here is an example from the official documentation

```js
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = storageRef.child('files/uid');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
  res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
    // All the prefixes under listRef.
    // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
  });
  res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
    // All the items under listRef.
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

I would suggest to use `list` method instead of `listAll` as the later stores all the results in memory while former uses pagination.

[Cloud Storage Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)

Comment: The question is asking about nodejs.  The Firebase SDK won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread and none of the solutions worked for me, I had to use stream to get what I wanted and then wrote my own script and put it in a gist in case it helps others.

https://gist.github.com/JonCatmull/fa55298fd55a565f246ab2e93c5c0e4b

My script just logs all the files over a certain size to a file but you could push them into an array and then perform operations on them if you want.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import yargs from "yargs";
import fs from "fs";
import { hideBin } from "yargs/helpers";
import { getStorage } from "firebase-admin/storage";

const argv = yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .option("bucket", {
    alias: "b",
    description: "bucket to copy images to",
    type: "string",
    demandOption: true,
  })
  .option("maxSizeMB", {
    alias: "m",
    description: "Max file size in MB",
    type: "number",
    demandOption: true,
  })
  .parse();

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp({
  storageBucket: argv["bucket"],
});

function logError(msg: string, file = "large-files-error.log") {
  console.error(msg);
  return fs.promises.appendFile(file, `${msg}\n`);
}

function log(msg: string, file = "large-files.log") {
  console.log(msg);
  return fs.promises.appendFile(file, `${msg}\n`);
}

const MB = 1024 * 1024;

try {
  const run = async () => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket();

    bucket
      .getFilesStream()
      .on("data", (file) => {
        const size = parseInt(file.metadata.size, 10);
        if (size > argv["maxSizeMB"] * MB) {
          log(`${file.name}
URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/${argv["bucket"]}/${file.name}
Size: ${(size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)}MB
--------------------`);
        }
      })
      .on("error", (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("done");
      });
  };
  run();
} catch (e) {
  logError(e);
}
```

## How to setup

### Install

Install gcloud
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Login and set project

```
gcloud init
# or just authorize
gcloud auth login
# then set project to the one that contains bucket
gcloud config set project [project-name]
```

Install script dependencies

```
npm i ts-node firebase firebase-admin typescript yargs @types/node
```

### Run

Run with ts-node and pass in bucket name and max file size (e.g. 10MB)

```
ts-node ./index.ts  -b your-bucket.appspot.com -m 10
```

Logs values to console and also creates a large-files.log file with path, url and size.